# Add items to Kendo Multiselect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd soo appreciate if someone could help.

I have Kendo Multiselect with no datasource initially:

```
@Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(model => model.Contract.ACCOUNT_NO).DataTextField("IBAN").DataValueField("IBAN")
```

And a function that appends items to this select:

```
    function getCustomerAccount(iban) {
            var ms = $("#Contract_ACCOUNT_NO").data('kendoMultiSelect');
            ms.dataSource.insert(0, { IBAN: iban, IBAN: iban }); //first insert to the dataSource

             //then insert to the textBox as selected item
            $("#Contract_ACCOUNT_NO_taglist").append("<li class='k-button' unselectable = 'on'><span unselectable='on'>" + iban + "</span><span unselectable='on' class='k-icon k-delete'>delete</span></li>"); 

            //next set inserted element prop to 'selected' (without this the Model does not accept selected items)
            $("#Contract_ACCOUNT_NO option[value=" + iban + "]").prop('selected', true);
        }
```

The problem is in setting prop of item to `selected`, it sets this property only to the last selected item. Why the props of previous items does not stay `selected`?

The second issue is when I delete last selected item, its `selected` property stays `true`.

My approach is to bind items I insert to the `textBox` directly to the `dataSource` of `MultiSelect`.

Comment: try using .attr('selected','selected')

Comment: @Exception, does not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not do such manual insertions - after adding the item to the dataSource, then use the [value](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/multiselect#methods-value) method of the MultiSelect to actually update the value.

e.g.

```
var oldValue =  multiselect.value().slice(); //create new array 
res.push(33); //add some more or new value    
multiselect.value(res)
```